# Azure ARM VNET: How to restrict RDP access to a specific set of IPs

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-virtual-network

I have 12 VMs defined in a Resource Groups. I need to restrict the RDP access to all of the12 VMs to a set of Internet IP addresses (about 28 of them)

What would be easiest way (or most efficient way) to fulfill this requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the same Network Security Group that filters RDP on all Subnets containing the VMs.

If you need to white list additional IP addresses you edit things in one place, the NSG.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-nsg/

Edit: MFA is also nice to have. I would actually lean towards that as an answer to your question. While the attack surface is larger, the management is easier, things are much more flexible for the end user and the attack difficulty is high to very high.

Comment: I have 28 separated IP addresses to authorize RDP access to them. How can I have one NSG rule that covers all of them?

Comment: Well if they're not part of the same /8 prefix or shorter (i.e. 91.0.0.0/8) then you can't. You'll need individual rules.